# How does this problem specifically correspond to a generalized eigenvalue problem?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Given two symmetrical square matrices $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and a rectangular matrix $W\in \mathbb R^{n,k}$. I want to maximize

$$\max_{W} \frac{\det (W^TAW)}{\det(W^TBW)}.$$

I read that the $W$ the maximizes this consists of the generalized eigenvectors that correspond to the largest eigenvalue in $$Aw_i=\lambda_iBw_i.$$

I know that this is true if we want to maximize $\frac{w^TAw}{w^TBw}$, $w \in \mathbb R^n$. However, I am not sure how this corresponds to the first optimization problem where we have a rectangular matrix $W$ and the determinant involved. Is there a way I can see this?

Comment: The vector case is only true when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric (or normal?). See numerical range and radius for related topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range. As a counter example let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=I_2$. You can check that the value is bigger when $w=[1 ~~ 3]^T$ even though the eigenvector with largest eigenvalue is $w=[1 ~~ 1]^T$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did mean symmetric matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix) the derivative of what you want to maximize with respect to $W$ is

$$ \frac{2 |W^TAW| |W^TBW| \left( AW (W^TAW)^{-1} - BW (W^TBW)^{-1} \right)}{|W^TBW|^2} = 0 $$
where $|\cdot|$ represents the determinant. So you need

$$ AW = BW (W^TBW)^{-1} (W^TAW) \tag{1} $$

It is easy to see that the solution satisfies $AW = BWX$ for some $X \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ and also

$$ \frac{|W^TAW|}{|W^TBW|} = |X| $$

Since the determinant is the product of eigenvalues you get your result.

However, one needs to take into the sign of the eigenvalues. For example, let the eigenvalues be $-1, -2, 1$. For $k = 1$, the maximizer is $w_3$, while for $k=2$, $W=[w_1 ~~ w_2]$ is the maximizer.

**Edit:** The specific equation in matrix calculus wiki is in the "Identities: scalar-by-matrix" table one previous from last row: "A is not a function of X, X is non-square, A is symmetric".

If $AW=BWX$ then from equation $(1)$

$$\begin{align}
AW &= BW (W^TBW)^{-1} (W^TAW)\\
&= BW (W^TBW)^{-1} W^T(AW)\leftarrow\text{Plug in here}\\
&= BW (W^TBW)^{-1} W^T(BWX)\\
&= BW (W^TBW)^{-1} (W^TBW)X\\
&= BWX
\end{align}$$

Let $X = T \tilde{X} T^{-1}$, then
$$\begin{align}
AW &= BW X\\
AW &= BW T \tilde{X} T^{-1}\\
AWT &= BW T \tilde{X}\\
A \tilde{W} &= B \tilde{W} \tilde{X}
\end{align}$$

where $\tilde{W} := WT$. So, without losing generality, we can assume that $X$ is in Jordan normal form. In particular, if $X$ is diagonal, then its elements correspond to the generalized eigenvalues of $(A,B)$. So, maximization of determinant can be done by selecting the eigenvalues that has maximum multiplication value. (If $X$ is upper triangular, then its diagonal elements correspond to the eigenvalues.)

**Edit 2.** Let $X(W) := (W^TBW)^{-1} (W^TAW)$. We want to solve
$$ \max_W |X(W)| $$
Therefore we need,
$$ \frac{\partial |X(W)|}{\partial W} = 2 |X(W)| \left( AW (W^TAW)^{-1} - BW (W^TBW)^{-1} \right) = 0$$
and consequently $W$ and $X(W)$ must satisfy
$$ AW = BW X(W) $$

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly do I get the information for obtaining the derivative as you did? I can't find it on the wiki

Comment: Sorry and another question: You say it is easy to see that the solution satisfies $AW=BWX$ for some $X$. However, when I solve the equation, I just get $AW=AW$, i.e. the equation is true for any $W$

Comment: I figured out my first question myself from the identity $\frac{\partial \operatorname{det}(X)}{\partial X} = \operatorname{det}(X)X^{-1}$. Still confused about my second question

Comment: Also, I dont understand how from the last argument "since the determinant is the product of eigenvalues" one gets the result? Could you please give me a short elaboration here?

Comment: @Tesla See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for your extended help, it clarified a lot. Still, I don't get the part where you introduce the matrix $X$. You write: If $AW = BWX$ and plug it into the equaton and of course get the result $AW=BWX$ as you claimed. And why not just set $X= (W^TBW)^{-1}(W^TAW)$ instead of saying that "there is some $X$"?

Comment: @Tesla Note that what I did was to assume there exists $X$ such that $AW=BWX$ and showed that if such an $X$ exists, our equation is consistent by plugging it in, where it turns out to be $X=(W^TBW)^{-1}(W^TAW)$. We could have done the reverse as you suggested, see my second edit. It is generally a choice of writing style between "let's see where these equations lead" vs "I already know the solution, let me show you why this is true".

Comment: I give a label to "our equation", so it is now equation $(1)$.

Comment: Promise, one last question, since it's also  been a while since my linear algebra classes. What's the distinguishment exactly when $X$ is diagonal or upper triangular?

Comment: When $X$ is diagonal the columns of $W$ are eigenvectors. Otherwise, they are just vectors such that when multiplied by $A$, they depend only on previous vectors, e.g. $A w_1 = \lambda_1 B w_1$, $A w_2 = x_{12} B w_1 + \lambda_2 B w_2$, $A w_3 = x_{13} B w_1 + x_{23} B w_2 + \lambda_3 B w_3$  and so on.

Comment: So this proof does not even show that $W$ consists of the eigenvectors correspoding to the largest eigenvalues in case $X$ is upper triangular?

Comment: If $W$ consists of the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues, then it is a solution. But there are infinitely many solutions as seen above. But all solutions yield the same result, that is the product of the largest eigenvalues.